# Setting a CSS value as a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Ok, I want to have a CSS value such as the value of width: 50%; to be a variable defined in pixels. Let's say that the 50% width is perhaps 1000px, or 500px. I want the javascript to detect the pixel value of the percent.

I have tried several times with absolutely no luck.

Comment: not very clear. do you want to detect a `width` of an element and then work of 50% of that?

Comment: No, what I want to do is have a percentage translated into pixel value with javascript.

Comment: The **@Azim**'s answer will put you right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like below using `jquery`.

```
var width = $('#your_id').width();
```

**Example**

```js
var width = $('#myDiv').width();
alert(width + 'px');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 200px;">
    <div id="myDiv" style="width: 50%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this would work fine, I will check mark it as soon as 7 mins are up(I have to wait 7 mins) BTW can you put width: 50% and do the same thing?

Comment: oh sorry I was looking at the first div. Thank you Azim!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var total_width = $( window ).width();
var display_width = 50; //50%
var my_width_px = ((display_width * total_width) / 100); // 100 = 100%
```

This will may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width in pixels using jQuery

```
var width = $('#mydivid').width();
```

Set the width of a div using jQuery

```
$("#mydivid").css("width", your_new_width);
```

Get width using javascript

```
document.getElementById("mydivid").offsetWidth;
```